Image in iText7 PDF Prints with Low Resolution
I am creating a PDF file using iText7 and adding an image to it. Generally, this works fine, but for some reason, the image appears in very low resolution when printed from the PDF. However, when I print the image directly from Windows, the resolution is excellent.
I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong. I've created a small sample repository to demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/MarvinKlein1508/IText7Resolution
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(memoryStream, new WriterProperties().SetCompressionLevel(0));
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
    float pageMargin = CalcCentimeterToPoints(PAGE_MARGIN_CM);
    document.SetMargins(pageMargin, pageMargin, pageMargin, pageMargin);

    PageSize pageSize = PageSize.A4;
    pdfDoc.SetDefaultPageSize(pageSize);
    string imagePath = "SchulzLF_0.png";

    float imageMargin = CalcCentimeterToPoints(IMAGE_MARGIN_CM);
    float nutzenHeight = (pageSize.GetHeight() / 2) - (2 * imageMargin);
    float imageWidth = pageSize.GetWidth() - (2 * imageMargin);
    float imageHeight = nutzenHeight;

    ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(imagePath);
    Image image = new Image(imageData);
    //image.SetAutoScaleHeight(false);
    //image.SetAutoScaleWidth(false);
    image.ScaleToFit(imageWidth, imageHeight);
    document.Add(image);
    image.SetFixedPosition(imageMargin, imageMargin);
    document.Add(image);
    document.Close();
    byte[] pdfBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

    await File.WriteAllBytesAsync("SchulzLF_0.pdf", pdfBytes);

}

Do I need to modify the image? If so, what should I consider to ensure it displays correctly in iText7?
The image should cover the entire A4 page, minus 0.5 cm margins on all sides, and half the height of the A4 page, also minus 0.5 cm margins.

@K J I have updated the repository so you will see why it needs to take half the space. Basically the image will be on the PDF twice. It will be printed on a label later on.

I don't understand the last part of your comment

The image also has been updated so if I understand you correctly then I have 2833/400dpi per image.
595 print units is 100% A4 width
842 print units is 100% A4 height
566 print units is A4 - 2 times my offset
392 print units is A4 / 2 - 2 times my offset
595-566 = 29 available space for both left and right
But isn't it just the positioning of the image? How does this impact the resolution of my image?

566.65 0 0 392.63 14.18 435.19 cm /Im1 Do Q q 566.65 0 0 392.63 14.18 14.18 cm /Im1 Do the positioning of the PDF generates almost like yours just with some decimal places

I notice that on my screen it is blurry in the pdf as well. When I try different DPI exports it will look different. 400 dpi is better than 300 but more than 400 make it much worse.

In which resolution should I provide the image? Notice that the PDF library scales it down to the 566x392 printer unit

Can you include the output PDF file (SchulzLF_0.pdf) in the github repository?

@iPDFdev I added it

I looked at the PDF file and the image is embedded at original size, no downscale. Can you include a screenshot/scan/picture that shows what you consider by "the image appears in very low resolution"?

@iPDFdev I've added two images https://github.com/MarvinKlein1508/IText7Resolution/tree/master/IText7Resolution/output

One of them is the printed output from same image from Microsoft Access and the other one is printed from iText7. You can see a clear difference in the middle text containers or at the text "Mindesthaltbarkeitsdatum" which is printed sideways

The PDF file is fine. The problem is the printing process that downscales the image very much (forward slashes are the easiest to see). How do you print the PDF file?

@iPDFdev I have printed both files on the same printer with exactly the same configuration. The printer used for this is an OKI Pro 9431dn.
Same PC, same printer, same settings. The only difference is the first PDF is generated using MS Access and the second PDF is generated using iText7

Please also add to GitHub the PDF file you generated from Access.

Hello @iPDFdev & @K J
Thanks for your help I found the solution. Your comments brought me into the right direction. The issue has something todo with the chosen software to print. When I print the PDF using Firefox it is blurry. When I print the same file using Edge or Adobe it is crystal clear.
Do you guys have any idea why Firefox prints the file differently?

Sorry, no ideea.
